# ContextMenu not updating parent change

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have following, straightforward example

```
 <ContextMenu x:Shared="false">
        <MenuItem Header="Usuń" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}"/>
        <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}">
            <MenuItem.Style>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="On"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="Off"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.Style>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
```

For the first time when it is created it sets Header's value to On, but in time property IsEnabled is set to false and no change is reflected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it seems like it's because the element's Parent didn't change. Try using a different RelativeSource (example untested):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1}}" 
             Value="False">
```

Comment: Exception is raised in your case. I tried using FindAncestor with AncestorType, then no changes are reflected as well.